# "Maximum file size allowed for upload: 0 bytes" showing while uploading files

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel, whm

"**Maximum file size allowed for upload: 0 bytes**" **showing** while uploading files. I have increased the limits via php.ini.

1. max_execution_time = 30
2. max_input_time = 60
3. max_input_vars = 1000
4. memory_limit = 128M
5. post_max_size = 500M
6. session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
7. session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
8. upload_max_filesize = 128M

**But NO RESULTS!! Any solutions?!**

Comment: Are you using a php framework? If so then mention it.

Comment: yes, I am using Php laravel framework.

Comment: Did you restart your HTTP server?

Comment: Create new file in the server and add below code. Load the page and view the phpinfo and find the correct php.ini path and change the values

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Per @biesior, stop and restart your server. This will load your new settings. .... However why this would have ever been zero in the first place, kinda seems that the config mitch match is elsewhere

Comment: yes! several times and the disk is used 40.3% only @biesior

Comment: Not following why the remaining space on the "disk" is relevant.

Comment: write the simple script: `<?php phpinfo();` and make sure that you're editing valid `php.ini` file, also check if your changes are taken into account.

Comment: also, check if you haven't it overridden i.e. in `.htaccess` file

Comment: Sorry @BalajiD I didn't see your phpinfo() advise before writing my comment.

Comment: there is more than just the PHP configuration involved, the server software also has configuration for these values

Comment: @lagbox, yes OP mentions laravel framework

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to restart your server every time you make changes in `php.ini`
also, these links will be helpful as they discuss same issue :

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/maximum-file-size-allowed-for-upload-0-error.564011/

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-do-i-increase-the-upload-limit-in-my-cpanel.69018/

Comment: This was already mentioned in comments. I guess putting it here makes it more visible.

Comment: Sorry @biesior , i just see your comment on the question with same advice

Comment: Problem is if OP is taking any of this advice, is silent about it. OP inserted a tangent about "disk space" earlier.

Comment: @IBRAHIMEZZAT No problem for me, however, we're only trying to guess, so I wouldn't try to answer what's a real problem until OP will give some more details.

Comment: Evidently, we're more interested then OP :D

Comment: I contact with service provider, they said the problem was with my Disk. "Problem solved!" Thank you guys for your time